# Google Analytics Separating Tablet and Mobile Traffic

Tags: google-analytics

I have a GA profile in which I'd like to separate out tablet and mobile traffic.
Google has out-of-box advanced segment for tablet and mobile; however Google's mobile segment INCLUDES tablet traffic. How do I include mobile phone only traffic?

I tried using screen resolution setting those screen width smaller than 7xx as phone, but it will exclude some high-res phones like Galaxy Nexus.

Answer (score 5):

This is an older thread, but the answer is new and it works.   To separate Tablet traffic from your site's Mobile traffic, you need to create a new "Advanced Segment."

1. Log in to Google Analytics
2. Go to the customer profile you want mobile stats for
3. Click the "Advanced Segments" link towards to top of the page (in the gray bar)
4. Click the "+ New Custom Segment" button
5. Enter a name for this segment, e.g., Mobile (not tablet)
6. Configure this: [Include] Mobile (Including Tablet) [Exactly matching] Yes
7. Click "Add 'OR' statement
8. Configure this: [Exclude] Tablet [Exactly matching] Yes
9. Click the "Save Segment" button
10. Return to the "Reporting" are in Google Analytics
11. Click 'Advanced Segments' again, choose your new "Mobile (not tablet)" custom segment
12. Click Apply
13. There's your metrics for mobile devices that are not tablets

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: In step 7, dont' you mean "Click "Add 'AND' statement" (AND instead of OR?)

Comment: Can I only include somehow desktop traffic?

Answer (score 2):

Since the last answer was posted Google have since created a default segment called 'Tablet Traffic' - using this segment it is possible to see only the traffic from a Google defined list of tablets.

It is worth noting that the default segment 'Mobile Traffic' includes the 'Tablet Traffic' segment. IE to get the visits from mobile phones (excluding tablets) you would sample the 'Mobile Traffic' and 'Tablet Traffic' default segments and minus the 'Tablet Traffic' segment from the 'Mobile Traffic' segment. This would give you traffic from mobile (phones) and traffic from tablets.

Comment: It looks like this has changed since you answered - now there are the following segments: "Mobile", "Tablet", "Mobile and Tablet", "Tablet and Desktop". It's gotten much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

Update Jul 2013: It's *finally* arrived in Analytics - http://www.chrisbell.eu/separate-mobile-and-tablet-segmentation-finally-arrives-on-analytics/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like GA doesn't have an easy way of doing this right now.  My thought is that you will have to exclude each tablet by specifically naming its Mobile Device Model.

e.g., Exclude>Mobile Device Model>Exactly Matching> Apple iPad

Answer (score 0):

The Koozai blog has a different approach to excluding Tablet traffic from mobile visits. The author segments her data by using Operating System and excludes a few resolutions.

http://www.koozai.com/blog/analytics/top-15-most-useful-advanced-segments-in-google-analytics/

You can build upon her segment and include other mobile operating systems as well as excluding additional resolutions.